# AngularJS - Display image using directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Image Constants**

```
angular.module('app-config', []).constant('imageConstant',
    {
        logoPath: 'assets/img/logo/',
        faviconPath: 'assets/img/favicon/',
        layoutPath: 'assets/img/layout/',
        logoFileName: 'myLogo.png'
    });
```

**Directive**

```
myApp.directive("streamingLogo", function () {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

    //pass image constants here to append image url
    //for ex: src = imageConstant.logoPath + imageConstant.logoFileName;

    };
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linker
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<img class="my-logo" id="my-logo" ng-src="{{src}}" streamingLogo/>
```

- I have configured image url and file names in a constant file. How do
  I pass it in a directive to append image path and name dynamically so
  that the it gets displayed using above directive ?

The idea is to have a configuration file for image path and names so that in HTML, only `ng-src="{{src}}"` is passed instead of full absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `imageConstant` dependency to your directive and you are good to go, like this:

```
myApp.directive("streamingLogo", ['imageConstant', function(imageConstant) {
   var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

       scope.logoPath = imageConstant.logoPath; 
       scope.favIconPath = imageConstant.faviconPath;
       scope.layoutPath = imageConstant.layoutPath;
       scope.logoFileName = imageConstant.logoFileName;

   };
   return {
       restrict: "A",
       link: linker
   };
}]);
```

Comment: @Slimshadddyyy That's because AngularJS add `src` attribute to the `img` tag because HTML only understands `src` attribute  on a `img` tag not `ng-src`(it a AngularJS specific)

Answer (score 1):

Inject `imageConstant` to your directive and add `app-config` as module dependency.

```
myApp.directive("streamingLogo", function (imageConstant) {

    var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.src= imageConstant.logoPath;
    };
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linker
    };
});
```

then in `linker` function

Then in HTML

```
<img class="my-logo" id="my-logo" ng-src="{{src}}" streaming-logo/>
```

**Note**

Change `streamingLogo` to `streaming-logo` on HTML

Answer (score 0):

You can inject your constant like any other angular provider:

```
myApp.directive("streamingLogo", ['imageConstant', function (imageConstant) {

var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {

console.log(imageConstant.logoPath);
console.log(imageConstant.faviconPath);
console.log(imageConstant.layoutPath);
};
return {
    restrict: "A",
    link: linker
};
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to inject constants as dependency for your directive

```
myApp.directive("streamingLogo", function (imageConstant) {

     var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {


    };
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linker
    };
});
```

notice that you need to inject your dependencies in other ways ([check this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di)) if you want to minifey  your javascript files for production.

```
myApp.directive("streamingLogo", ['imageConstant',function (imageConstant) {

     var linker = function (scope, element, attrs) {



    };
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: linker
    };
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the `imageConstant` into the `.directive` function.

```
var myApp = angular.module('app-config', []);

myApp.directive("streamingLogo", ['imageConstant', function(imageConstant) {
   return {
       restrict: "A",
       link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
         scope.logoPath = imageConstant.logoPath; 
         scope.favIconPath = imageConstant.faviconPath;
         scope.layoutPath = imageConstant.layoutPath;
         scope.logoFileName = imageConstant.logoFileName;
       }
   };
}]);
```

**small change in Html code :**

use `streaming-logo` instead of `streamingLogo`.

```
<img class="my-logo" id="my-logo" src="{{logoPath}}" streaming-logo/>
```